# How to display a list of duplicate files with WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I'm writing a program that finds duplicate files in a folder and displays them. I want the user to be able to select and delete files in the duplicate list.

The duplicate list is contained in a `Dictionary<byte[], List<string>>` where the key is a file's hash and the value is the list of files that produced this hash.

I don't know if there is a relevant widget in WPF to do that or if I have to write one. What is the simplest way of showing and manipulating this list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to transform the `Dictionary` into an `ObservableCollection<T>` where `T` might be a `string` that contains the duplicate file name.

Once you did that, you'll be able to bind to that `ObservableCollection` using any of the items controls WPF provides out of the box (usually through the `ItemsSource` property), such as: `ListBox`, `ComboBox`, `ListView`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, do you know any `ObservableCollection` that can be used as a `Dictionary` or has similar features, or do I have to implement it myself ? It seems very simple but boring as hell :P

Comment: Sorry, but no, there is no "Observable Dictionary" available out of the box, you'll need to do the boring stuff ;-)